# Can I know which controller was called in @ControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, annotations

now, I using the @ControllerAdvice in Spring 4.*.
using beforeBodyWrite method.

create custom annotation in controller class.
get the information of controller when @ControllerAdvice processing.

I want to know that request coming from what's controller class.

but, I don't know the solution.

any help.?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `beforeBodyWrite()` is in `ResponseBodyAdvice`. You want to know the controller that was executed there? If so, why?

Comment: I need to know annotation of controller. create custom annotation class then, define annotation class on method level in controller class. cause,  I need to reset the data by annotation before messageConverter execution.

Comment: a very poorly asked question, please read this page first and then edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Although your question doesn't state clearly what is the purpose of what you are achieving and why do you need to create a custom annotation I'll post you some guidelines showing how to determine the source of your `RuntimeException` inside the `ControllerAdvice`

Given the following Rest controllers:

```
@RestController
public class CARestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testException() {
        throw new RuntimeException("This is the first exception");
    }
}

@RestController
public class CAOtherRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test-other", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testOtherException() {
        throw new RuntimeException("This is the second exception");
    }
}
```

Which both throw an exception, we can capture this exception by using the following `ControllerAdvice` and determine the origin of the exception using the stack trace.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CAControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = RuntimeException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<String> handleRestOfExceptions(RuntimeException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(String.format("%s: %s", ex.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName(), ex.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

This is how the output of the endpoints will look:

[image: Output of First Controller]
[image: Output of second Controller]

My recommendation is that instead of doing this, you declare your own set of exceptions and then capture them in your controller advice, with independence of where they were thrown:

```
public class MyExceptions extends RuntimeException {
}

public class WrongFieldException extends MyException {
}

public class NotFoundException extends MyException {
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class CAControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = NotFoundException .class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotFound() {
        /**...**/
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(value = WrongFieldException .class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleWrongField() {
        /**...**/
    }
}
```

Comment: The source of his `RuntimeException`?

Comment: ControllerAdvice is used to capture RuntimeExceptions which are unchecked and don't need to be declared in the method as `throws`. It's a better practice (in my opinion) to do this way although I can edit the answer.

Comment: Exception handling is a common use for `@ControllerAdvice`, but it's not the only one. He wasn't saying anything about exceptions. In fact, it's unclear what he's saying, and whether it's related to `@ControllerAdvice` at all...

Comment: You're right, my bad, I misinterpreted the question. It really needs some editing.

Comment: Thanks! very helpful for me. I have an idea!